# HTML error message returned when expecting XML

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

We have a situation where we are expecting an error message in XML to be returned from Quickbooks online, however, we're getting the following message back from the API with a status code of 400.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>JBoss Web/2.1.12.GA-patch-03 - Error report</title>
  <style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> 
</head>

<body>
  <h1>HTTP Status 400 - message=No destination found for given partition key; errorCode=007001; statusCode=400</h1>
  <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <p>
      <b>type</b> Status report
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>message</b> <u>message=No destination found for given partition key; errorCode=007001; statusCode=400</u>
    </p>
    <p>
      <b>description</b> <u>The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect (message=No destination found for given partition key; errorCode=007001; statusCode=400).</u>
    </p>
    <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
    <h3>JBoss Web/2.1.12.GA-patch-03</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems like the client has an expired trial account. Should our code handle this type of error, or is this Intuit's problem because they're not returning an XML message?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Intuit, but wouldn't "The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect" suggest that the error is syntactic and not an expired account?

Comment: Can you post your request or the URL you're hitting, so we can see what you're doing?

Answer (score 2):

If you make request without error and get this response, probably your account on Quickbooks doesn't exist.

I faced with this issue. When I go through oauth flow. I get correct oauth key & secret. But when I make api call, so get the same error. I discovered that my account (which I use for make API call) doesn't exist in Quickbooks. With other existing account it works fine.

Hope this help.